# Spring : Restrict injection of Repository module in Controller

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm building a REST Webservice using Spring Boot (v 1.4.2.RELEASE). I'm trying to follow separation of concerns pattern, so I've created 3 maven projects,
myapp-repository, myapp-service and myapp-rest. myapp-service has a dependency of myapp-repository and myapp-rest has a dependency of myapp-service. Below is the initial configuration I've made.

**myapp-repository**

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Repository Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.myapp.repository")
@EntityScan("com.mycompany.myapp.entity")
@PropertySource("classpath:repository.properties")
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.primary.datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

**myapp-service**

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-repository</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Service config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.myapp.service")
@Import(RepositoryConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:service.properties")
public class ServiceConfig {

}
```

**myapp-rest**

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Rest config

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.myapp.rest")
@Import(ServiceConfig.class)
public class RestConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to restrict my repository services to be autowired in myapp-rest, but with this current implementation, it's possible. Only services inside myapp-service module should be allowed to autowire in myapp-rest. Is it possible?